# Changing Support URL in Azure Marketplace application

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I am having an app published to the Azure marketplace. The **Support and Help** tags under the Support category lead to the same webpage that is added for the support page.
Is there any way I could change this and point help and support both to different pages?

[image: app screenshot]